# iWork Numbers How To Calculate - In Once Cell Function - The Elapsed Time In Hours Between Two Date/Times?

Tags: macos, numbers, iwork

Let's say I have two date/times. The start date/time is 29th May 2020 at 20:30 and the end date/time is 30th May at 02:30. [This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3705969) link shows how to calculate using two cell references.

How to calculate *in one cell* the duration?

Something like [DATEDIF](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/functions/ffa55ea982/web) but *accepting the time and output of result in hours*, e.g.:

```
=MYCLEVERDATETIMEDIFF(“29/5/20 20:30”, “30/5/20 02:30”, "H")
```

which results in:

```
6
```

Six being the elapsed time in hours between the above date/times.

What function, or combination of functions and conversions would do the trick? Note that ideally something that works as one cell function, *not calculating the difference between two cell references.*

Any ideas?

Comment: See this for the logic and there are others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57962394/4961700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I have understood what you wish to accomplish correctly, here is one way of doing it in the same cell if you are willing to enter the dates and the times separately:

[image]

And here is the text version of the formula shown above

```
=(DATEDIF(DATE(2020,5,29),DATE(2020,5,30),"D")+TIMEVALUE("02:30")−TIMEVALUE("20:30"))×24
```

Unfortunately, this can not be done by entering the date & time together for each point in time (or without entering them more than once). It appears that there is no date & time function in Numbers that calculates the difference between two date & time values in hours directly or one that fully converts a date & time value in text or otherwise to a proper date & time value that Numbers can process.

Comment: Nice, thanks!

Weird but this also works!... 
=24−((TIMEVALUE("29/5/20 20:30")−TIMEVALUE("30/5/20 2:30"))×24)
An issue with both however is they return numbers rather than duration type. 

In either case one can then add the DURATION function as follows to complete:

=DURATION(,,(24−((TIMEVALUE("29/5/20 20:30")−TIMEVALUE("30/5/20 2:30"))×24)))

Comment: Happy to hear that you figured out other formulas that may work for you. Pls note that the formulas you suggest right above would calculate the difference in hours correctly only if the dates are consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

Just click a cell and type the equals sign, then add DateDif(ref cell 1, reference cell 2,"D"). You can enter reference cell 1 and 2 by just clicking on the proper cell. This command will return the number of days between the two dates. It is done in one cell.

Comment: Hi @jmh sorry I probably wasn't clear enough. I'm looking for a function that will do everything in one cell. That is, without referencing other cells. Also, unless I'm mistaken, I think DateDif only works with years, months, days. It won't give a result in hours.

Comment: what are you trying to calculate that requires no reference cells?

Comment: the elapsed time in hours between a time yesterday and another time today.

Comment: if you have the result in days just multiply by 24 to get hours. You can make the line be 24*DATEDIF.

Comment: You just put today's date in a cell and tomorrow's date in another cell then use those two cells as reference cells.

Comment: DATEDIF("29/05/20 20:30","30/05/20 02:30","D") returns 1. Multiplying that by 24 gives 24, which is incorrect. There's six hours between those two dates. Regarding the referenced cells, that is true that's one way. The question is however, is there a way to do everything as function(s) within one cell?

Comment: There is also a HOUR and MINUTE function. I don't think you can do what you want in 1 cell though.